# Google Sheets Select Row that contains text and transpose it in a single step

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I'm trying to select a row of data from my table based on text in columns A and B and then transpose it into a column.  In my example, I would like to just have Minnie Mouse's information in a single column.  I'm able to accomplish this in 2 steps, by first transposing the data and then filtering it (circled in my image), however I'd like to do it in a single step.  I've tried combining the TRANSPOSE and FILTER functions but I always get an error.  I was able to use QUERY and "select" but that only returned the name, "Minnie" and not the rest of her information.  [Link to sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A05MDbtuf0-i4sMiIbXZbqOMvhGhzNTzmuU2tkQtQlo/edit#gid=0)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be filtering first, then transposing. Almost all spreadsheet functions expects data to be found in a single row, as this is how the convention works. I'll be using the **corrected** references.

Using the `FILTER` function:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A2:E6,A2:A6=G3,B2:B6=H3))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, David Tan.  I think that might be one of the variations I already tried.  I just tried plugging it in and  gave me and #N/A error (no matches)

Comment: Hm, strange. Mind sharing a link to your spreadsheet? That will help immensely here.

Comment: Thanks, David.  The link is in the original post.

Comment: I have it working on my end now. the cell references were off, so I shifted them by down.